# How to use pandas to csv with separator as space and without double quoting the text

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to write a python script that basically reads up the CSV/TSV file (sample of input from CSV as  below) using Pandas readCSV into a dataframe

```
0,18778586,Toys,5,0,0,N,Y,Great Quality!!!,2015-08-31,excellent!!!,35.6,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.6784
```

Then I remove un-needed column with the dataframe by only keeping column[1] , column[8] respectively and do an apply function which strips the special characters from column[8] and converts it to lower-case
Then I am trying to use pandas write CSV from the dataframe to as a txt so that it looks like it

```
18778586 great quality
```

whereby the format is there is a document ID (numeric) separated by a space with string (text). The string can contain spaces.

Basically I've tried the various combinations below :-

1. Changing the separator - This sort of works but the separator from ID and the text is another character. I can't seem to use this file directly with the system as it expects a space
2. Using escapechar . This sort of fixes the issue but the problem is the text portion are double spaced instead of single space. I am trying to avoid this
3. Using Pandas(DataFrame) toString + Writing it as txt file - now it gets what I am looking for but it seems to be truncating the text - unless there is a way to get it to print the whole text instead of truncating it like a table

Obviously I could write another program which reads through the output file and removes the double space or replace the first tab it sees with space. That should be as last resort if there aren't any solution

```py
df.to_csv(filename,header=False,sep=' ',index=False,doublequote=False,quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE,escapechar=' ')
```

That code currently gives me the following output . Note the double spacing

```
18778586 great  quality
```

Comment: would u pls share a sample of the source?

Comment: This is the source

0,18778586,Toys,5,0,0,N,Y,Excellent!!!,2015-08-31

So you have row id , review id , categories , rating and few others and excellent. I've managed to load up in pandas and built a column. I am trying to strip special characters out , make it all to lower and just grab the review id and the comment so that it becomes like the output

Comment: so u want to just replace `commas` with `spaces`?

Comment: @Samha' I am trying to do the following . Read the raw file with commas -> make the text to lower case/remove un-needed character --> strip un-needed the column and save the output file whereby there is the review id + text

Comment: If my answer helped u with your question, pls accept it by clicking the check mark beside it.

Answer (score 0):

**Use `tab`s as output separators, or replace in-field spaces with `NON-BREAKING spaces`!**
Supposing u have a file named `test.csv` containing the below:

```
0,18778586, Toys,5,0,0,N,Y,This is fantastic,2015-08-31
0,18778586,  Toys,5,0,0,N,Y,Excellent!!!,2015-08-31
0,18778586,Toys,5,0,0,N,Y   ,Excellent!!!,2015-08-31
```

U can apply `applymap` to apply `strip` method or any processing u might want to do to each cell.

*When using `space` as an `output separator`, pandas will wrap output fields that contain spaces like this, `"This is fantastic"`.*

- *Using `tabs \t` as output separator works around this*.

```py
df = pandas.read_csv('test.csv', header=None)
df = df.applymap(lambda x: str(x).strip())
df.to_csv(path_or_buf='out.txt', sep='\t', header=False, index=None, columns=[1,8])

# out.txt
# 18778586        This is fantastic
# 18778586        Excellent!!!
# 18778586        Excellent!!!
```

- *Another workaround to get the desirable output, is to replace the in-string spaces with `non-breaking spaces`*.

```py
...
df = df.applymap(lambda x: str(x).strip().replace(' ', u"\u00A0"))
...

# out.txt
# 18778586 This is fantastic
# 18778586 Excellent!!!
# 18778586 Excellent!!!
```

Comment: In my output file , there are double quotes between the space which is what I am not looking for. It goes back to my earlier problem or issue with it

Comment: 0,18778586,  Toys,5,0,0,N,Y,This is fantastic,2015-08-31
I am extracting This is fantastic + the ID , so we are talking about column[1,8]

Comment: Your solution works if the comment does not contain space - here is the output

RDIJS7QYB6XNR excellent

If the comment does contain space , then it will wrap with quotes which is not what I am looking for


R36ED1U38IELG8 "great quality wooden track better than some others we have tried perfect match

Comment: @python_learner94 this is the output I get after running my code. `18778586 "This is fantastic"`

Comment: so u don't want the quotes around `"This is fantastic"`?

Comment: Yep I do not want the quotes that gets wrapped. This happens because of the separator being space , now If i use CSV Quote None - it will throw an exception because it can't tell the difference between a separator and the text. Hence that's the problem statement.

@Samha' - Yes . I do not want the quotes to be there :)

Comment: @python_learner94 u can use `tab \t` as `separator` instead of `space`, and this will be enough to resolve the conflict and prevent quoting as well.

Comment: Tried that , i cannot feed it in as the software is expecting \s and not \t. Anyway , I guess i need to use sed to do replacement of tab to space. It looks like it cannot be output into one